# does this inequality imply the Cauchy Schwarz inequliaty?

Tags: inequality

Let $z_i,w_i \in \mathbb{C}$. My teacher in class proved the following inequality:

$$ \Big( \sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm{Re}(z_jw_j)  \Big)^2 \leq \sum_j |z_j|^2 \cdot \sum_j |w_j|^2$$

Question: Does this inequality imply the Cauchy Schwarz inequality:

$$ \big| \sum_j z_jw_j\big|^2 \leq \sum_j |z_j|^2 \cdot \sum_j |w_j|^2$$

???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does. Pick a $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$e^{i\varphi} \sum_{j=1}^n z_jw_j$$

is a non-negative real number. Then

$$\left\lvert \sum_{j=1}^n z_j w_j\right\rvert = e^{i\varphi} \sum_{j=1}^n z_j w_j = \sum_{j=1}^n (e^{i\varphi}z_j)w_j = \operatorname{Re}\sum_{j=1}^n (e^{i\varphi}z_j)w_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \operatorname{Re} \bigl((e^{i\varphi}z_j)w_j\bigr).$$

Now square, apply the first inequality, and note that $\lvert e^{i\varphi}z_j\rvert = \lvert z_j\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have a confusion, why can you pick a number $\varphi$ ??

Comment: Because $\{ e^{i\varphi} : \varphi \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert = 1\}$, which gives you the polar form of complex numbers. If the sum is $0$, any $\varphi$ will do, the product is always $0$. If $$\sum_{j=1}^n z_jw_j = s \neq 0,$$ then write $s$ in polar form, $s = \lvert s\rvert\cdot e^{i\psi}$, where $\psi$ is an argument of $s$. Then you can take $\varphi = -\psi$, or more generally, $\varphi = 2\pi k - \psi$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.